# Mask a function from `ls` in R

Tags: r, rprofile

I want to put the following function in my .Rprofile to make installation of bioconductor packages easier:

```
install.bioconductor <- function(...) {
  source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
  biocLite(...)
}
```

But when I load a new R session, this function is now listed when I call `ls`. Is there a way of masking the function from being shown?

Comment: You could name it `.install.bioconductor`, and then it will only show up when you do `ls(all=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in its own environment and attach that environment to the search path.

```
myFUNs <- new.env()
myFUNs$install.bioconductor <- function(...) {
  source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
  biocLite(...)
}
attach(myFUNs) # attach to the search path
rm(myFUNs)     # remove from .GlobalEnv

# it is still accessible via 
# install.bioconductor(...)
```

Then it be accessible, but will not show up in `ls()`.  (You can see what is attached to the search path with `search()`, and you can see what is in `myFUNs` with `ls(myFUNs)`)

Alternatively, as @JoshuaO'Brien mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707019/mask-a-function-from-ls-in-r/17707132#comment25804581_17707019) you can keep it in the `.GlobalEnv` but add a dot to the beginning of the name (i.e. name it `.install.bioconductor`) so that it will be "hidden" such that it won't show up with `ls()`, but will show up with `ls(all.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: Is there a way to mask `myFUNs` from `ls` as well? Both solutions are good, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I think I need to sit down and write a package to hold my utility functions.

Comment: @Manetheran, after you've `attach`ed it to the search path, you can just remove it from your `.GlobalEnv` with `rm(myFUNs)`